# ENONET no such file and directory , stat E:\client\build\index.html

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Hey I am working on a project in which I am integrating both node js and react js at same port but I got stuck while setting the path for static files. I don't know how to set it even after researching on whole stackoverflow  , please guide me .

Here is how I am loading static files in server.js :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build/')});
});
```

Here is my directory image .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

res.sendFile("views/index.html", { root : __dirname});

or in your case:

res.sendFile("cleint/build/index.html", { root : __dirname});

I think the problem is:

> '../../

Comment: more clear would be: 
res.sendFile("index.html", { root : path.join(__dirname,"client","build")});

Comment: I putted wrong photo check again , and also I was reciving error : URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'